# Ansible & with_items naming

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I need to have the following in my Ansible playbook:

```
with_items: "{{ ab36-1E }}"
```

The above doesn't work and leads to an error in Ansible 2.1 and 2.2 versions.

```
{"failed": true, "msg": "template error while templating string: unexpected char u'E' at 8. String: {{ab36-1E}}"}
```

However, this works: `with_items: "{{ ab361E }}"`

`{{ab36-1E}}` is a dictionary variable defined in a YAML file and referred to in the playbook.

I am wondering if there is a way to use `{{ ab36-1E }}` instead of `{{ ab361E }}` within `with_items` in Ansible.

Comment: What is `ab36-1E`? not a valid variable in Ansible What are you trying to do?

Comment: Remember, in ansible within {{ }} you're essentially writing ninja.  With items would expect a list.  You appear to be giving it a string, but not enquoting it so jinja can't parse.

Comment: Updated my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible and it's not limited to `with_items`.

[What Makes A Valid Variable Name](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#what-makes-a-valid-variable-name):

> Variable names should be letters, numbers, and underscores. Variables should always start with a letter.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification !